# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter with multiple row views

Tags: android

I am new to programming with java and android. So my project has been a huge learning experience. I am using a cursorloader that retrieves data from a database and then assign that data to the custom adapter. What I am trying to do is take that data and based on what that data is, assign it to a certain row layout.

There will be around 6-12 different layouts. The data contains different types of devices, e.g. light, dimmer, thermostat, etc. Each type of device is associated with a category number. A light would have a category of 3 and a dimmer a category number of 2. I want to check that category and depending on the number, assign it to a certain row layout. How would one go about doing this? I am trying to create a custom simplecursoradapter. This is what I have so far, however it crashes.

```
public class DeviceAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private LightViewHolder lightholder;
    private TempViewHolder tempholder;

    public DeviceAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        if (cursor.getString(4).equals("17")) {;
            tempholder = (TempViewHolder)view.getTag();
            tempholder.name.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            tempholder.temp.setText(cursor.getString(10));
            tempholder.tempImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.thermometer);
        } else if (cursor.getString(4).equals("3")) {
            lightholder = (LightViewHolder)view.getTag();
            lightholder.name.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            lightholder.status.setText(cursor.getString(10));
            lightholder.lightImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_on);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            holder.name.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            holder.status.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (cursor.getString(4).equals("17")) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.temperature_device_list_item, null); 
            tempholder = new TempViewHolder();
            tempholder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.devicename);
            tempholder.temp = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.temp);
            tempholder.tempImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tempImage);
            view.setTag(tempholder);
            return view;
        } else if (cursor.getString(4).equals("3")) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.light_list_item, null); 
            lightholder = new LightViewHolder();
            lightholder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.devicename);
            lightholder.status = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.status);
            lightholder.lightImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.deviceImage);
            view.setTag(lightholder);
            return view;
        } else {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.device_list_item, null); 
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.devicename);
            holder.status = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.status);
            view.setTag(holder);
            return view;
        }
    }


    private static class LightViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView status;
        ImageView lightImage;
    }

    private static class TempViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView temp;
        ImageView tempImage;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView status;
    }

}
```

Does this look right? bare in mind I am new to all of this and it has been hard trying to find some good examples. Most code examples are calling getView and I read that you should use bindView and newView.

My application has a fragment of rooms and a fragment that contains the list of devices. The crash happens when I click one room, the list will display the devices. If I go and click a different room, the application will crash and I get the following:

```
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.garrettpower.powerha.listadapters.listview.DeviceAdapter$LightViewHolder cannot be cast to com.garrettpower.powerha.listadapters.listview.DeviceAdapter$ViewHolder
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at com.garrettpower.powerha.listadapters.listview.DeviceAdapter.bindView(DeviceAdapter.java:42)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:251)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1949)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1756)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1302)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1587)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1800)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9588)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9588)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9588)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9588)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9588)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9588)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1542)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1403)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1314)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9588)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:9588)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:3877)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1288)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2046)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-17 03:41:07.033: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can anyone help me? There has to bee a good way of doing this. I keep reading that try adding getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType. The problem is, I am confused on how to implement this. I have looked at many code samples and still confused.

Comment: can not we use the same ViewHolder and the layout?, make the imageview invisble for the 3rd type of layout during bindview()

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old but in case anyone comes across this from Google or something.

The problem was that `bindView` tried to cast a `TempViewHolder` to a `ViewHolder`  -- both of these are custom inner classes defined in the adapter, and because they are different they cannot be cast from one to the other.

It's important to never **assume** a `ListView` is giving you the same view type in the  `convertView` as the one you need.

At least that's what the stack trace shows.  There may be other problems but fixing that would reveal the next issue.

Comment: Just to be clear the code you have here is not giving you a `convertView` it is just returning a reusable view that it has, but with a `SimpleCusrorAdapter` it doesn't support different view types out of the box. A `BaseAdapter` on the other hand does